# How to use Slater Type Orbitals as a basis functions in matrix method correctly?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, matrix, numerics, special-functions

This question is a continuation of my previous series of questions about basis functions.

I would like to find the minimum energy of Coulomb potential motion using matrix method.

$H=-\frac{1}{2}\Delta-\frac{1}{r}$

I have chosen Slater Type Orbitals as a basis functions $R(r)=Nr^{n-1}e^{-r}$ ,$ \quad n = 1, 2, 3, 4, 5...$ (formula 11.2.2 from here https://chem.libretexts.org/Courses/Pacific_Union_College/Quantum_Chemistry/11%3A_Computational_Quantum_Chemistry/11.02%3A_Gaussian_Basis_Sets )

The answer is known from the general theory ($E_{min} = -0.5$)

My Wolfram Mathematica code give the next values:

$E_{min} = -0.874888131489401$ - 5 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -1.7871262624523565$ - 10 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -2.407853444926228$ - 15 basis functions 
$E_{min} = -2.858626490878647$ - 20 basis functions

The increase in basis functions number gives increase in the absolute value of the energy and it is so far from -0.5. But with increase of the basis functions number, the energy value should get closer to the correct value. What have I done wrong?

The code:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
nmax = 5;
Psi1[r_, n_] := r^(n - 1) Exp[-1*r^2];
NN[n_] := 
  1/Sqrt[Integrate[Psi1[r, n]*Psi1[r, n]*r^2, {r, 0, Infinity}]];
Psi[r_, n_] := NN[n]*r^(n - 1) Exp[-1*r^2];
(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := 
  FullSimplify[
   Psi[r, n2]*
    Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];
Kx[n1_, n2_] := -0.5*Integrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
KK = Table[Kx[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];

(*potential energy*)
VP1[r_] := -1/r;
Px1[n1_, n2_] := 
  Integrate[Psi[r, n2]*VP1[r]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}];
PP = Table[Px1[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];
Coulomb = Min[Eigenvalues[KK + PP]]

Out[2009]= -0.874888
```

Comment: [Cross-posted to math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4651845). Please don't do that, especially not without linking the questions to each other and explaining your reason for cross-posting. It wastes everyone's time.

Comment: @Roman, thanks for the reply! Could you please comment on my questions in the comment section below your answer )

Comment: @Roman, could you please look at my questions below

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your orbitals are not orthogonal to each other: here I've normalized them with an explicit formula (using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to discover it):

```
Psi[r_, n_] = 2^(n + 3/4)/Sqrt[(2 n - 1)!! Sqrt[π]] * r^(n - 1) E^(-r^2);

Table[Integrate[Psi[r, n1] Psi[r, n2] r^2, {r, 0, ∞}], {n1, 0, 5}, {n2, 0, 5}] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Therefore, you need to solve a [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem). Alternatively, you can ortho-normalize your basis vectors with the [Gram–Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

Corrected code (generalized eigenvalue problem):

```
nmax = 10;
Psi[r_, n_] = 2^(n + 3/4)/Sqrt[(2 n - 1)!! Sqrt[π]] * r^(n - 1) E^(-r^2);

(*kinetic energy*)
Kk[r_, n1_, n2_] := FullSimplify[Psi[r, n2]*
  Laplacian[Psi[r, n1], {r, \[Theta], \[Phi]}, "Spherical"]];
Kx[n1_, n2_] := (-1/2) Integrate[Kk[r, n1, n2]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}];
KK = Table[Kx[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];

(*potential energy*)
VP1[r_] = -1/r;
Px1[n1_, n2_] := Integrate[Psi[r, n2]*VP1[r]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}];
PP = Table[Px1[n1, n2], {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];

(*basis function overlaps*)
B = Table[Integrate[Psi[r, n2]*Psi[r, n1]*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}],
          {n1, 1, nmax}, {n2, 1, nmax}];

Min@Eigenvalues[{KK + PP, B} // N]
(*    -0.480814    *)
```

#### derivation of the generalized eigenvalue problem

The time-independent Schrödinger equation in operator form is

$$
\hat{H}\left|\psi\right>=E\left|\psi\right>
$$

Multiplying from the left with an orbital $\left<i\right|$ gives

$$
\left<i\left|\hat{H}\right|\psi\right>=E\left<i|\psi\right>
$$

Now we write $\left|\psi\right>=\sum_jc_j\left|j\right>$, which is possible even if the orbitals $\left|j\right>$ are not ortho-normalized. Inserting this expression we get

$$
\sum_j c_j \left<i\left|\hat{H}\right|j\right>=\sum_{j'}c_{j'}E\left<i|j'\right>
$$

The "usual" assumption of $\left<i|j\right>=\delta_{ij}$ is not satisfied here (we don't have ortho-normalized basis functions).

Let's call $H$ the matrix with elements $H_{ij} = \left<i\left|\hat{H}\right|j\right>$, and $B$ the matrix with elements $B_{ij}=\left<i|j\right>$. The Schrödinger equation becomes

$$
\sum_j H_{ij} c_j = E \sum_{j'} B_{i j'} c_{j'}
$$

or, in matrix writing:

$$
H\cdot\vec{c} = E B\cdot\vec{c}
$$

This is a generalized eigenvalue problem. For ortho-normalized basis functions, $B$ is the unit matrix and the problem becomes a regular eigenvalue problem $H\cdot\vec{c} = E \vec{c}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But I have two questions: Could you please explain this line: Min@Eigenvalues[{KK + PP, B} // N], is there orthonormalization? And why, if I put 20 functions appears some complex part?

Comment: With 20 orbitals there seems to be a bit of a numerical problem. I've modified the code a bit to work with the normalized (but not orthogonalized) orbitals: it makes the problem a bit easier but there are still complex numbers appearing for $n_{\text{max}}=20$.

Comment: There is no orthogonalization when using a generalized eigenvalue problem. I'll add a derivation.

Comment: For $n_{\text{max}}=20$ we seem indeed to run into numerical difficulties. The [matrix condition number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number#Matrices) of $B$ is larger than $10^{22}$, exceeding the numerical precision of machine-double numbers, and so the condition that $B$ is positive-definite is no longer strictly true at the numerical level. Increasing the working precision (beyond machine-double numbers) helps: `Min@Eigenvalues[N[{KK + PP, B}, 100]]` still gives a good answer.

Comment: Thanks! It is really very good explanation!

Comment: I only now notice that you use not normalized functions in the code. My code have the normalization coefficient NN, but you don't use it, why it work correctly with not normalized functions?

Comment: @MamMam please check the given derivation of the general eigenvalue problem: there are no assumptions on the basis functions. They don't need to be normalized, and they don't need to be orthogonal.

Comment: Yes, I understand, thank you very much for the reply! I have one more question about this problem. By writing this equation $H\vec{c}=EB\vec{c}$ in Mathematica ```Eigenvalues[{KK + PP, B}]```  it is given eigenvalues of non-orthogonal basis set. ```Eigenvectors[{KK + PP, B}]``` gives eigenvectors components, but these eigenvectors not normalized. If I understand correctly normalization condition in the case of non-orthogonal basis set is $N^2\vec{c}^TB\vec{c}=1$ where N is normalization coefficient. Is there some special entry in Mathematica to easily find normalization coeff. N?

Comment: If it's not difficult for you, please demonstrate it. I need the normalize wave functions, because I need to continue to work with them.

Comment: In the case of orthogonal basis set I would do it just like this: ``` Psii[j_] := Sum[CC[[j]]*Psi[j], {j, 1, n}] ```  next  ``` NN[j] := 1/
  Sqrt[NIntegrate[
    Psii[j]*Psii[j]*r*2*Pi, {r, 0, Infinity}, {z, -Infinity, 
     Infinity}]]  ```  next  ```  PsiN[j_] := NN[j]*Psii[j](* normalized wave function *)  ```. But in the case of non-orthogonal basis set it doesn't seem too obvious.

Comment: *in the previous massage consider the case when the wave functions are real and the integral is written in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: @MamMam Once you have `{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[{KK + PP, B} // N]` you can normalize the eigenvectors with `nevec = Normalize[#, Sqrt[# . B . #] &] & /@ evec`. Then you have, for example, `f1[r_] = v[[1]] . Table[Psi[r, n], {n, nmax}]` as the first eigen-function. Check that it is normalized properly: `Integrate[f1[r]^2*r^2, {r, 0, ∞}]` gives 1.

Comment: Thanks for explanation! Likely this is a typo, ```nevec[[1]]``` Instead of ```v[[1]]```?

Comment: Now to find the average of some operator, like the square of coordinates, I have to do it in the following way ```Integrate[f1[r]*r^2*f1[r]*r^2, {r, 0, \[Infinity]}]```? In other words, this construction ```f1[r_]``` is now a normalized function, which must be used for further operations.

Comment: Yes that was a typo, sorry!

Comment: Thanks for the very useful explanation! This construction ```nevec = Normalize[#, Sqrt[# . B . #] &] & /@ evec``` doesn't change the order of the normalized eigenvectors with respect to the order of eigenvectors before normalization operation ```{eval, evec} = Eigensystem[{KK + PP, B} // N]```? That is, the order of the eigenvectors before and after normalization is the same? I ask it because in general I understand this type of construction but I don't have much experience using it at the moment.

Comment: In one of the previous questions here (Mar 4 at 12:44), I asked about using the normalization coefficient in basis functions, although it is not necessary. I asked this because in this article (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05553.pdf) the authors use the normalized coefficient $N_j$ in the their non-othogonal Gaussian basis set (formula 2). I really don't understand why?